# How (or, if) to avoid cross-dependencies between classes

Tags: c#, oop, sorting, inheritance, collections

I'm working on an exercise that involves implementing a simple card game (similar to rummy).

So, I have a `Card` class which has `suit` and `rank` members. I have a `Cards` class which inherits from `List<Card>`.

I'm writing code to check for winning conditions, which involves finding whether a player's hand contains runs (9H, 10H, JH, QH) or matching sets (2H, 2D, 2C).

So, I'm implementing code on the `Cards` class to find any runs or sets contained in the collection. The first step for finding a run (at least, the way I'm implementing it) is to sort by suit, then by rank. And then, the first step to finding matching sets is to sort by rank, then by suit (I guess sorting by suit is not strictly needed, but I'm implementing it that way to make sure the cards always sort in a predictable order).

So, I have created a class `CardComparerSuitRank : IComparer<Card>` and another class `CardComparerRankSuit : IComparer<Card>`. Then, if you call `myCardsInstance.FindLargestSet()`, the first thing the method does is create a shallow copy of the `Cards` instance called `cardsToSearch` and call `cardsToSearch.Sort(CardComparerRankSuit.Default)`, and then it iterates through `cardsToSearch` and notes the largest matching set.

While I was working on this, though, I realized that this was creating an implicit dependency on `CardComparerRankSuit` for my `Cards` class. To provide all of its exposed functionality, `Cards` depends on the comparer class. This seems bad since, in my mind, a class ought to encapsulate all the functionality it exposes (or at least, if it depends on another class, that dependency should be explicit like through inheritance).

So, my question is, what pattern do I use to avoid this scenario? I bet there's a way to write the class so that this functionality is fully encapsulated, but that seems like it leads to writing an enormous, hard-to-read class definition. Or can I, through some combination of class/interface inheritance, divvy the functionality up more sensibly among multiple source files? Or should I just lighten up and stick with the pattern I described above and not worry so much?

Comment: Shouldn't be better if `Cards` contain `List<Card>` and implements `IEnumerable` rather than inherist `List<Card>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely odd that you are deriving from `List<Card>`. Composition (holding an instance of `List<Card>`) is preferred over inheritance in this case.

To explain that a little, your "Cards" class is not a "type of" `List<Card>`. It "has" a list of cards. "Type of" relationships are inheritance, "has a" relationships are composition.

As far as your dependency on the comparer class goes, that makes total sense to me. Dependencies are almost never solved through inheritance, but through aggregation/composition as you already have. The only change you *could* make is to have your comparers derive from some "ComaprisonStrategy" interface so that you can inject a mock into the "Cards" class for unit testing.

Just to clarify, if the reverse was true, that the comparer class was dependent on "Cards" that would be a problem, since a comparison shouldn't care where the source came from.

Let me know if I can clarify anything!

Answer (score 1):

Implement `CardComparerSuitRank` and `CardComparerRankSuit` as private classes nested in the `Cards` class. You don't expose the mechanism behind the sorting and any dependencies are hidden in the `Cards` class.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have done the whole class structure differently actually. You really want your classes to represent the real world as much as possible, especially if you're actually trying to represent a real scenario with real-world objects.

In the real world you have a game of cards with players who all have a number of cards in a hand. Each player looks at his hand and decides if it's a winner or not. If he's won, he says so when appropriate and the game is over.

So for a software game you need a Game object that will control it all. You need Player objects to add to the Game's Players array. Each Player has a Hand object that contains an array of Card objects.

The Game object creates a number of Player objects and passes each of them a Hand object.

Later, it iterates through each Player object and asks them if they have a winning Hand which is done by each Player object calling some method/property in the Hand class which uses System.Collections and IComparer to decide if it's a winner or not.

Comment: While a reasonable design, this doesn't seem to really address the specific question of "is this dependency ok".

Comment: "So, my question is, what pattern do I use to avoid this scenario? "

Comment: It does have a similar structure to what you're describing, actually. The "Game" level object will contain the actual rules for what constitutes a winning hand. But it will call on the Cards object (collection of Card in a player's hand) to determine whether the hand contains the appropriate combinations of Card to trigger a win.